# cmake: difference between "make install" and "make package"

Tags: cmake

I'm using CMake to generate my makefiles. My deployable target is an RPM, and that's all working well. Per the file system guidelines, my RPM installs to

```
/opt/mytool
    /bin - executables
    /lib64 - libraries
/etc/opt/mytool - configuration files
```

The RPM gets built by CPack using `make package`

During development testing, I don't want to install an RPM. It requires elevated privileges and limits any given machine to one (developer) version at a time. Before I got all the RPM stuff working, I was able to "make install" and create a simple `install` tree like this:

```
install
    /opt/mytool
        bin
        lib64
```

However, the introduction of the config files to a different location has gummed up the works. I'd like this to be extended to include

```
install
    /etc/opt/mytool
```

but I can live without it. Unfortunately, when I try `make install` I get this error:

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Debug"
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:49 (file):
  file cannot create directory: /etc/opt/mytool.  Maybe need administrative
  privileges.
```

The offending part of the `CMakeLists.txt` file is

```
install(FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Config/mytool.cfg
    DESTINATION /etc/opt/mytool
)
```

I've looked at [CMake rpm installing a file in /etc/init.d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442824/cmake-rpm-installing-a-file-in-etc-init-d), but my RPM builds just fine (and I'm using CMake 3)

What is the difference between `make install` and `make package` (I can infer that the latter is running CPack, and it works just fine)? How can I create a development install tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two build targets is that `package` creates an RPM file in your case while `install` copies the resources given to the [`install()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/install.html) command to the location provided to the `DESTINATION` parameter:

> DESTINATION
>
> Specify the directory on disk to which a file will be
>   installed. If a full path (with a leading slash or drive letter) is
>   given it is used directly. If a relative path is given it is
>   interpreted relative to the value of the [CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html)
>   variable. The prefix can be relocated at install time using the
>   DESTDIR mechanism explained in the [CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) variable
>   documentation.

You specified to copy files to `/etc/opt/mytool` for which you obviously have no write permissions and encounter the cited error.

You have two options to resolve this, the second one is clearly preferred, because it allows every developer to provide their own, system-local setting, where to temporarily install dev files:

- set a `DESTINATION` path for which you have write permissions
- set a relative path and call `cmake` with an additional argument to specify where your development install tree is:

```sh
cmake -H<source path> -B<build path> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<install path>
```

Comment: if I do that, won't it break my RPM?